# Driver installation of r8188eu or rtl8188ftv (not sure which one to install)

Tags: networking, drivers, usb

```
modinfo r8188eu | grep F179
alias:          usb:v0BDApF179d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
```

2   `sudo dmesg | grep r81`

```
percpu: Embedded 60 pages/cpu s208896 r8192 d28672 u524288
pcpu-alloc: s208896 r8192 d28672 u524288 alloc=1*2097152
r8188eu: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
usbcore: registered new interface driver r8188eu
r8188eu 1-5:1.0 wlx00e04c818802: renamed from wlan0
```

**Results corresponding to last suggestions**

sudo dmesg | grep -e r81 -e wlx

```
percpu: Embedded 60 pages/cpu s208896 r8192 d28672 u524288
pcpu-alloc: s208896 r8192 d28672 u524288 alloc=1*2097152
r8188eu: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
Modules linked in: snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg i915 snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm r8188eu(C+) ttm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi drm_kms_helper snd_seq cec snd_seq_device rc_core input_leds joydev snd_timer snd soundcore coretemp kvm_intel i2c_algo_bit fb_sys_fops syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt video kvm mac_hid serio_raw sch_fq_codel ipmi_devintf ipmi_msghandler msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic gpio_ich psmouse i2c_i801 i2c_smbus sky2 pata_acpi lpc_ich floppy usbhid hid
usbcore: registered new interface driver r8188eu
r8188eu 1-5:1.0 wlx00e04c818802: renamed from wlan0


lsmod | grep 8188
r8188eu               671744  0
```

I have a PC so I can't physically go and stand right next to the router but anyway I used

```
nmcli device wifi list
```

and this is what I got   `IN-USE  BSSID  SSID  MODE  CHAN  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY`

Comment: The question which was answered before mine was about rtl8188fu however mine is about rtl8188ftv. I tried these steps before posting the question but it didn't work for me that's why I asked that question again.

Comment: I believe the device is covered by the driver *r8188eu* that's included by default in Ubuntu 22.04. Please edit your question to show the result of the termminal command: `modinfo r8188eu | grep F179` and also: `sudo dmesg | grep r81` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: It appears that the driver loaded and an interface was created: wlx00e04c818802. Does it see networks? `nmcli device wifi list` No need to post the result, just tell us if it does or does not see your network. If it does, can you click on the Network Manager icon and connect?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: Is there any way to resolve this problem?

Comment: Let's have a look at more diagnostics: `sudo dmesg | grep -e r81 -e wlx` Also: `lsmod | grep 8188` Does it see your network if you stand right next to the router? `nmcli device wifi list`

Comment: Unfortunately, your edits have removed entirely the original questions and data that should have been additions, not replacements. The original question is gone. If possible, revert and reorganize your edits. As is,the question is not even a question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the fault @chili555 . Let me know if there is anything else which is to be revised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we see above, the built-in driver r8188eu does not work. Let’s try a better driver. With a working internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install –reinstall build-essential bc git dkms
git clone https://github.com/kelebek333/rtl8188fu
sudo dkms add ./rtl8188fu
sudo dkms build rtl8188fu/1.0
sudo dkms install rtl8188fu/1.0
sudo cp ./rtl8188fu/firmware/rtl8188fufw.bin /usr/lib/firmware/rtlwifi/
```

Now let’s blacklist the built-in driver:

```
sudo -i
echo “blacklist r8188eu”  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
echo rtl8188fu >>  /etc/modules
exit
```

Reboot.

Comment: It worked!! Thanks!