# Wireless usb apapter not show any available networks

Tags: network-manager, usb-drive, 22.04, usb-modem, realtek-wireless

Ubuntu 22.04 is recognising the Realtek RTL8188FTV 802.11bUSB Wifi adaptor, but no available networks show

[image]
[image]
[image]

**lsusb**

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0bda:f179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188FTV 802.11b/g/n 1T1R 2.4G WLAN Adapter
```

**nmcli dev status**

```
nmcli dev status
DEVICE           TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION         
enp3s0           ethernet  connected     Wired connection 2                 
enp2s0           ethernet  unavailable   --                 
wlx00e04c818802  wifi      unavailable   --              
lo               loopback  unmanaged     --
```

**lshw -C network**

```
lshw -C network
*-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: a
       bus info: usb@2:1.3
       logical name: wlx00e04c818802
       serial: 00:e0:4c:81:88:02
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8188eu driverversion=5.15.0-39-generic multicast=yes wireless=unassociated
```

**sudo iwlist sca**

```
sudo iwlist sca
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.
enp2s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.
enp3s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.
wlx00e04c818802  No scan results
```

There are no Driver show in **Additional Drivers** Tab, how to resolve this issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: Possibly https://askubuntu.com/questions/1415272/driver-installation-of-r8188eu-or-rtl8188ftv-not-sure-which-one-to-install :)

Answer (score 1):

I got the exact same issue in my Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.
It was recognizing RTL8188FTV 802.11bUSB Wifi adaptor but not scanning any network.

So, What I did (after spending a whole day on it):

1. Install and configure the `rtl8188fu` driver by following this [repo](https://github.com/kelebek333/rtl8188fu)
   (I executed only following commands)

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential git dkms linux-headers-$(uname -r)
git clone https://github.com/kelebek333/rtl8188fu
sudo dkms add ./rtl8188fu
sudo dkms build rtl8188fu/1.0
sudo dkms install rtl8188fu/1.0
sudo cp ./rtl8188fu/firmware/rtl8188fufw.bin /lib/firmware/rtlwifi/

sudo mkdir -p /etc/modprobe.d/
sudo touch /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8188fu.conf
echo "options rtl8188fu rtw_power_mgnt=0 rtw_enusbss=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8188fu.conf
```

2. Black List `r8188eu` driver in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

> Edit this `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` file to add `blacklist r8188eu` at the end of file.

3. Finally reload the newly installed driver using following command
   `sudo modprobe -rv rtl8188fu && sudo modprobe -v rtl8188fu`
4. Now reboot the system.

#### Summary:

1. Install and configure a new driver `rtl8188fu`
2. then backlisted the already existed driver `r8188eu`
3. then reload the newly installed driver
4. reboot system.

That's all.

Let me know if you need more help. I'd be happy to help you.